# How to disable stock management for one of the assigned sources on a product? Multi Source platform setup

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, stock, multi-website

I am running a multi-source setup on Magento 2.3 platform.

I create two different stock sources and assigned them to a product in my catalogue as such:

[image]

I would like to **disable** stock management for "Stock Source 1", however, keep the stock management for "Stock Source 2". Is this possible with out the box Magento functionality? "Advanced Inventory" settings seem to be global rather than per stock source.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the "backorders" option for sources with MSI Product Sources Configuration extension.

[image]